# Unable to install ReactJS library on Windows 7

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to install reactjs on my windows 7 machine using the following command:

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

But I am getting the following errors:

```
Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....npmjs.org/jsonfile/-'
90 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
90 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
90 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
90 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
91 verbose cwd E:\WORK
92 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7600
93 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "-g" "create-react-app"
94 verbose node v10.14.1
95 verbose npm  v6.4.1
96 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....npmjs.org/jsonfile/-'
97 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 2):

update your npm version or try to clean the corrupted cache of npm by using

```
npm cache clean --force
```

after running above command try to install again react

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```